# Do more expensive paths bring more visitors than stone paths?

Tags: dragonvale

[Visitors like paths](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/59861/11920). But is it just the amount of paths, or the amount of money put into the paths?

Do gold/brick/marble paths bring more visitors to your island than stone paths, block per block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly, Stone Paths appear to be *better* at attracting visitors. To test this I filled one island *completely* with either sort of path.

Stone Paths: 185 visitors

[image]
Marble Paths: 93 visitors:

[image]

Some other stuff in my park changed between the two screenshots, but the stone paths I added in the first screenshot actually added more than 100 visitors on their own, so it seems pretty clear **Stone Paths have unholy visitor attracting power**.